# Copying a specific XML block from a log file using Groovy script

Tags: regex, groovy

I am trying to extract a specific block from a big log file via Groovy. I have a big log file that contains blocks of XML similar to this:

```
<Block start tag>
....
...
<ID>1</ID>
...
...
<Block end tag>

.....

<Block start tag>
....
...
<ID>2</ID>
...
...
<Block end tag>

....

<Block start tag>
....
...
<ID>2</ID>
...
...
<Block end tag>
```

and so on

I want to extract only the block that contains the  value of 2. Currently I am trying with:

```
String starttag="Block start tag"
String endtag="Block end tag"
//log.info string

def extract= (fileContents =~  /(?s)<${starttag}.*<ID>2</ID>.*${endtag}>/)
```

but the system is copying all the text from the first block that contains value of 1 up until the last one.

How can I configure the regular expression to search specifically for a block from all available in the log file that contains a specific value in a specific tag?

Comment: seems your question `how to write regular expression`. so add a tag `regexp` to it.

Comment: Did it. Thank you for noticing :)

Answer (score 0):

I create a sample xml:

```
<root>
    <Block12311qwwqw>
        <def>4</def>
        <ID>1</ID>
    </Block12311qwwqw>
    <Blocksads123wqasd>
        <some>1</some>
        <ID>2</ID>
    </Blocksads123wqasd>
    <Blocksqweqsari234812w8sqq>
        <test>3</test>
        <ID>2</ID>
    </Blocksqweqsari234812w8sqq>
</root>
```

And this code:

```
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(xmlText)
xml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'ID' && it.text() == '2' }*.parent().each {
    println it
}
```

Returns:

```
Blocksads123wqasd[attributes={}; value=[some[attributes={}; value=[1]], ID[attributes={}; value=[2]]]]
Blocksqweqsari234812w8sqq[attributes={}; value=[test[attributes={}; value=[3]], ID[attributes={}; value=[2]]]]
```

**EDIT 1:**

Based on your comment, you can add dummy root tag for this case and it should work:

```
String xmlText = "<root>" + originalLogText + "</root>"
```

originalLogText is:

```
<block>
    <def>4</def>
    <ID>1</ID>
</block>
<block>
    <some>1</some>
    <ID>2</ID>
</block>
<block>
    <test>3</test>
    <ID>2</ID>
</block>
```

Comment: Hi, my idea is to copy a block similar like the *<root>* one that you have given as an example from a big .log file that contains dozens of blocks with the same name. The regex that I want to use is to capture only the XML block that contains a specific value, like  *<ID>2</ID>*.

I have tried your code but somehow it is not working with me, I guess because the original file is not .xml but a .log file... so basically I need a regex which will capture only this specific block from the big log file.

Comment: Hmm, something is not compatible with the file again :( Is there a way that we can do the search in the format that I have listed in the initial post?

Comment: Actually I apply code to the same format from your message, maybe it contains not well formatted xml. I add sample to the answer. Can you put here exception message you see?

Comment: The problem is that this log file does not contain only XML structured data , it contains also other data of the processes tha tare executed. That why I have defined start and end tag of the XMl that I want to use and try to find the block this way. Basically, I am not seeing any error, but I receive blank response when I execute the script and no data is found.

Comment: Okay, now it's more clear. I will think how to handle it.

Comment: Any luck finding a solution?

Comment: Not yet, I didn’t have a chance to check it. I guess I’ll continue tomorrow.

Comment: Any luck so far? :)

Comment: I did some tests, but unfortunately I have no success. I have one more proposal, I'm not sure does it will work, but anyway, you can try to read only lines which starts with "<" and parse the result String as an xml string. This "workaround" should solve the issue, when you faced with different kind of records in your log file.